# Bash regex count hyphen backwards

Tags: regex, bash

Given the following input format:

```
blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli-1.2.3-xxx-1blo
```

I want to have 2 regex to get:

1. `blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli`
2. `1.2.3-xxx-1blo`

There's no guarantee that the first part ('blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli') will always have two -, but it's 100% certain that the second part ('`1.2.3-xxx-1blo`') will always have two `-`, and between part one and two will always have `-`

I managed to do this using `cut` but it's slow for massive operations. So I'm hoping that using bash regex can improve performance. Also, I tried this `[^-]+(?:-[^-]+){2}$` in regex101.com and it works, but in bash it doesn't:

```
test='blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli-1.2.3-xxx-1blo'
[[ $test =~ [^-]+(?:-[^-]+){2}$ ]]; echo $BASH_REMATCH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
str="blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli-1.2.3-xxx-1blo"

if [[ $str =~ ^(.*)-([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)$ ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

Output:

```
blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli
1.2.3-xxx-1blo
```

BTW `test` is a reserved command name and it is recommended not to use it as a variable name.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`?:` is used to signal a non-capturing group in other regex impl but this doesn't seem to work in bash: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html

Try without it:

```sh
[[ $test =~ [^-]+(-[^-]+){2}$ ]] && echo matched=$BASH_REMATCH
```

Prints:

```
match=1.2.3-xxx-1blo
```

By the way I used the `&&` operator and added additional printout to indicate whether the match operation succeeded.

*Edit:*

To get the first part you can make use of string stripping functionality of bash: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22828

```sh
[[ $test =~ [^-]+(-[^-]+){2}$ ]]
second=$BASH_REMATCH
first=${test%-$second}
echo $first $second
```

prints:

```
blablabla-blebleble-bliblibli 1.2.3-xxx-1blo
```

Comment: Nice! It works for case 2. Any thoughts on how to get case 1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp, that anchors to the end of the line will do the work

```
(.*)-([^-]*(-[^-]*){2})$
```

in the first part `(.*)` you match any string that can be before our character of interes (which comes next to it and is the `-` that separates both groups)

The second part `([^-]*(-[^-]*){2})` matches a sequence of chars not in the group of the `-` followed by two groups (`{2}`) of a sequence of chars different than `-` preceded by a `-` (`-[^-]*`).

It is worth commenting that the string `---` will match, and will return as valid groups "" and "--" (you can test this in the sample demonstration [here](https://regex101.com/r/urJhof/1))